# Item level permission based on groups rather than user

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, permissions, item-level-permissions

Is it possible to achieve item level permission on a list based on groups instead of users? 
I'm referring to the Item-Level Permissions option in Advanced settings. It enables you to changes Read access to "Read items were created by the user" and Create and Edit access to "Create items and edit items that were created by the user" I would like to use the same option on a group level.

I would like to have one list where different user groups enter data. Each group should be able to create and edit their items but only the admin should be able to see all information.

I'm using SharePoint online.

Comment: Thanks for the previous answers. Tho, what I try to achieve via Item-Level permissions is different and hasn't been answered. I amended the question accordingly. Help is very much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

**Yes,** you can provide permission to a group on item level. To achieve this please follow the below steps :

1. Go to your list, Select item.
2. Click on **Items** from the top ribbon.
3. Click on **Shared With**. From the popup, Click on **Advanced**.
4. From the Top Ribbon, Click on **Stop the inheritance**.
5. Then click to Grant Permission to provide a unique permission to specific group/user.
6. Provide the User/Group name and select Permission Level by clicking on **Show Options**.
7. Click on **Share**.

Don't forget to upvote and make it as answer if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can add users instead of groups on item level permission.
Just stop inheriting permission on list -> then click Grant Access -> provide user ID then click OK. By doing this only that particular user can view that item on the list.

But best approach is provide the group name instead of user ID , then only it will not mess up anyway in the future and it will be more easy to track the permission level

Answer (score 0):

I'd question why you would want to go down that route, it will quickly make managing permissions a mess.

Consider creating additional groups instead or even splitting your items in to separate lists if you need to customise the security by individuals or groups.

### Reading

Check out this post by the [SP Maven on item level security](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-enable-item-level-permissions-in-sharepoint/), you might also like to read [this one on Sharepoint Permission Levels](https://sharepointmaven.com/sharepoint-permission-levels/) in case you need extra info on permissions.